# Developing android application with a development web service

Tags: android, web-services, android-studio

I'm currently building an Android Application and an accompanying Web Service. Right now I'm having some trouble figuring out the best way to configure the Android Application to know where the Web Service is. When I use the emulator and I'm running a local dev version of the web service, I manually tell the Android Application that the web service is hosted at "10.0.2.2". This works well for the emulator, but not for a physical device. I'm able to access it, via my phone, over the LAN using it's IP address, so actually accessing the web service is not the problem. It's just a pain to have to change the IP when I want to run it on my phone. Is there some configuration I could use to make this task easier?

Comment: Why not just make a config file for your phone and the emulator.  That way every time you start the app, it reads the config file on whichever device it's running on, then handles things appropriately.

Comment: @Kristy Welsh I was hoping there was something built in for it. I have several devices, and other people's devices. It would be time consuming to install a file on each of them. Also, my laptop's I address isn't static, so I'd need to change that configuration file anyways, which is the situation I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: You should be able to use the LAN ip address of the server in both the emulator and device

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that you could do something similar to what I was asking using some gradle.

http://jeremie-martinez.com/2015/05/05/inject-host-gradle/

This post shows you how to add the ip address of the development computer to the code at compilation time.